# MySQL Abysmal Performance when Inserting with PDO Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, insert

Recently, I have been trying to figure out why a particular PHP script is taking so long.  It is a simple group permissions grid that takes N checkboxes from the front end for each group and updates the permissions table accordingly.  Simple stuff.

To minimize round trips to the DB, I have simply been truncating the table and re-inserting rows for each permission.  Doing this, I am seeing absolutely abysmal performance on the insert step.  Everything is wrapped up in a transaction and all queries are using PDO prepared statements.

**The database** itself is MySQL and all tables are using the InnoDB engine.  The specific table being inserted into is SUPER simple, consisting of only 3 columns as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `024_group_privs` (
  `group_priv_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `activity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_priv_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `group_id` (`group_id`,`activity_id`),
  KEY `activity_id` (`activity_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `024_group_privs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `023_groups` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `024_group_privs_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`activity_id`) REFERENCES `031_activities` (`activity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=98 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

As you can see, a basic many-to-many mapping table.

**The PHP code** in question (with test scaffolding that generated the subsequent results) is as follows:

```
<?php
try {

    //Connect to database
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');

    //Begin transaction.  If there are any errors; this will ensure we still have
    //  a good set of permissions when rolled back
    $db->beginTransaction();

    //Prepare insert and select statement
    $ins_perm = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 024_group_privs (group_id, activity_id) VALUES (:group_id, :activity_id)");
    $get_act_id = $db->prepare("SELECT activity_page_key FROM 031_activities WHERE activity_id = :activity_id");

    //Nuke existing permissions list; it will be re-built shortly and is faster than
    //  trying to 'true up' the differences in existing permissions with the new ones.
    $trunc_s_time = microtime(true);
    $db->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
    $db->query("TRUNCATE TABLE 024_group_privs");
    $db->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
    $trunc_e_time = microtime(true);
    print("Trunc time = " . ($trunc_e_time - $trunc_s_time) . "<br/><br/>");

    $tot_ins_time = 0;
    $tot_sel_time = 0;

    //Get grout names from DB, do not trust POST object.
    $query = "SELECT group_name, group_id FROM 023_groups";
    foreach($db->query($query) as $row) {

        //Get current group and related checkbox array.  The names of these arrays are
        //  populated from the DB when the initial page is rendered.
        $group_name = $row['group_name'];
        $group_id = $row['group_id'];
        $perms = $_POST[$group_name];

        //Rebuild permissions for this group
        foreach($perms as $activity_id) {

            //Testing for select statement timing
            $sel_s_time = microtime(true);
            $get_act_id->bindValue(':activity_id', $activity_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $get_act_id->execute();
            $result = $get_act_id->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $sel_e_time = microtime(true);
            print("Sel time = " . ($sel_e_time - $sel_s_time) . "<br/>");

            //Insert new permission <-- THIS IS THE SLOW QUERY
            $ins_s_time = microtime(true);
            $ins_perm->bindValue(':group_id', $group_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $ins_perm->bindValue(':activity_id', $activity_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $ins_perm->execute();
            $ins_e_time = microtime(true);

            print("Ins time = " . ($ins_e_time - $ins_s_time) . "<br/><br/>");
            $tot_ins_time += ($ins_e_time - $ins_s_time);
            $tot_sel_time += ($sel_e_time - $sel_s_time);
        }

    }
    print("<br/>Total Sel time = " . $tot_sel_time . "<br/>");
    print("Total Ins time = " . $tot_ins_time . "<br/>");
    print("Total time = " . $tot_ins_time + $tot_sel_time . "<br/>");

    //Commit changes
    $db->commit();

    //Close DB connection
    $db = null;

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    set_mysql_status($sid, "An error occurred while processing your request: " . $ex->getMessage());
    $db->rollBack();
}
?>
```

**The results** of my testing are as follows (shortened for brevity):

```
Trunc time = 2.1458051204681

Sel time = 0.00010895729064941
Ins time = 1.2832479476929

Sel time = 0.00010108947753906
Ins time = 1.2832760810852

Sel time = 0.00010204315185547
Ins time = 1.2749929428101

Sel time = 0.00011420249938965
Ins time = 5.0466451644897

Sel time = 0.00012516975402832
Ins time = 4.5408680438995

...

Total Sel time = 0.010221719741821
Total Ins time = 168.57392191887
```

**The Question**:  what gives?  I would expect that the compiled insert statement would execute much faster than that, especially with such simple data, more along the lines of the select statement.  The data is tiny; less than 100 rows per table.  There are no table locks as this is my private (dedicated) development environment and the box itself has nothing else running on it and PLENTY of horsepower to do simple DB transactions.

**My Understanding / Expectations**:  DB round trips should be minimized both as a result of the prepared statement and the transaction 'wrapper'.  My only thoughts are that it is as a result of the two foreign keys on the table, but that would be pretty pathetic given the data size compared to the machine that is processing it.  Perhaps MySQL is forcing a full hard drive write with each insert, but that seems like it would defeat the purpose of the transaction in the first place.

I have searched Google and SO, though most of the problems I have found center around preparing the query inside the loop or something similar.

One last note:  this code has not been optimized for security and is aimed at testing slow inserts.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: As far as I can see you are using emulated prepared statements try array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false) as 4th parameter to PDO to see if performance improves.

Comment: I am mighty tempted to -1 this question. for "to minimize roundtrips" and for distinct table per group

Comment: Anyway, **The main question:** if you are suspecting foreign key - why don't you run **one single insert query** in console? Without transactions, without prepared statements, without PDO. without long ans windy PHP code?

Comment: @Common Sense:  I don't understand what you mean by 'distinct table per group'?  I only have one group table and one permissions table?  That aside, I ran it in the console and the performance I see is roughly the same.  Though, it was my understanding that the prepared statements should be faster than that as the remove the need to do all of the string parsing and such on the query.

Comment: @hidden: That worked wonders, though I have no idea why.  If you submit that as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Can you please define "wonders" in certain numbers? How much it's improved? Did it take any time for prepare?

Comment: The values obviously change linearly with selection size, however my worst case (total insert execution time) was previously ~160 - 170 seconds.  That is down to ~4 seconds for that same input set.  So, yeah, 'wonders' is apt.

Comment: If it's true, and not some sort of measurement error, this would be first time in my life I see prepared statements works [ever noticeable] faster than regular query. I am so eager to see a sensible explanation, to the point of offering huge bounty to an able person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling native prepared statements:

```
   array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false)
```

as 4th parameter to PDO resolves the issue, as to why it helps is better to ask on DBA stackexchange.

Comment: It cannot be a cause.